# Odata v4 and axios request for React native has error on IOS only, Android has good response

Tags: react-native, axios, expo, odata, microsoft-dynamics

I have used a get Axios request with Backend Dynamics 365 that has Odata for Rest APIs.

I have a good response on a get request API that has no parameters. But When I use other get APIs that have a parameter, then I get an error response with data.

```
"data": Object {
  "error": Object {
    "code": "",
    "message": "The supplied company name is not valid.",
  },
},
```

API URL:

Request type: GET

```
/APP/ODataV4/Company('United%20Traders%20Syndicate%20P.Ltd')/AppVehicles?$filter= appUsername eq 'SUMBEAST'
```

**This error does not occur in android.**

Comment: Can you check if the response object is typed correctly? It looks like you have some dangling JSON keys like `API URL`.  And what is the link at the bottom starting with `/APP...`. Is it part of the response you get?

Comment: Issue somehow solved when removing /Company('United%20Traders%20Syndicate%20P.Ltd')/

Answer (score 0):

Issue some how solved by removing

```
/Company('United%20Traders%20Syndicate%20P.Ltd')/
```

removed the required part from the API with help of backend developer
guess ios doesnot take % properly